# What program/language should I use to create Notion widgets?

Tags: widget, embed, notion-api, web-widget

I'm interested in learning how to create/code embedded widgets, specifically Notion-based (the multi-purpose workspace app) widgets such as [blocs.me](https://blocs.me) and [indify.co](https://indify.co)

And I'm not quite sure what programming languages, apps, or frameworks they used. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can [apply](https://notionup.typeform.com/to/BXheLK4Z) to get access to the [Link Previews API](https://developers.notion.com/page/link-previews-api). You can use any language that implements an HTTP client and server.